# Log likelihood of mixture distributions

Tags: maximum-likelihood, mixture-distribution

If I have a gamma mixture distribution represented as,
$$f(x;\alpha,\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}\pi_if(x;\alpha_i,\beta_i)$$
Where $\pi$ represents the weights of the $N$ components. For $N=2$ and the distribution having $K$ samples, the maximum likelihood estimate is given by,

$p(x;\pi_0\pi_1,\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\beta_0,\beta_1) = \prod_{i=1}^{K} (\pi_0\Gamma(x_i;\alpha_0,\beta_0)+ \pi_1\Gamma(x_i;\alpha_1,\beta_1))$

Then the log-likelihood can be written as,

$\log(p(x;\pi_0\pi_1,\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\beta_0,\beta_1)) = \sum_{i=1}^{K} (\log(\pi_0)+\log(\Gamma(x_i;\alpha_0,\beta_0))+ \log(\pi_1)+\log(\Gamma(x_i;\alpha_1,\beta_1)))$

Is this evaluation of log-likelihood correct?

Comment: No,$$\log(ab+cd)\ne\log(a)+\log(b)+\log(c)+\log(d)$$There is no easy representation of the log-likelihood that leads to a closed form MLE.

Comment: Ah ok, I used the EM algorithm to estimate the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ values of the mixed distributions and the weights. How do I compute the maximum likelihood of this in order to use them in AIC to find the goodness of the fit?

Comment: EM returns the MLE of the entire parameter vector. You can check our survey https://hal.science/hal-01961077v1/file/CFSR.pdf for details of using AIC and BIC in mixture models.